# Laravel belongsToMany - Get Parent All Categories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, belongs-to

I can not speak English well. Iam Sorry.
i want to do, get all categories to which the category with id 5 is attached

where is error editing ?

Database:

[image: Database ScreenShot]
Categories.php

```
class Categories extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'parent_id',
        'slug',
        'title',
        'description'
    ];

    public function parentCategories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Categories::class);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function AddDetail(AdvertAddDetail $request){
    $selected = Categories::find($request->select);
    print_r($selected->parentCategories());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write column as below,

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Categories::class, 'parent_id');
```